# I can't install a package because it asks a dependency version higher than the available one

Tags: debian, apt, git, dependencies

It's hard to make it clearer than the title.

I upgraded from debian 9 to 11 yesterday, and somehow my git package got dumped on the way.
So naturally I tried to reinstall it this morning. One problem, it asks me for a dependency that doesn't exist.

```
 ~ sudo apt install git                                                                  100 err | 10:50:02
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but 2.31-13+deb11u4 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

 ~ sudo apt list libc6 -a                                                                100 err | 10:51:09
Listing... Done
libc6/stable,now 2.31-13+deb11u4 amd64 [installed]
```

The libc6 dependency that git is asking makes no sense whatsoever because the one listed on the debian website for my version is 2.28 ( https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/git ).

My best guess is that my problem comes from my sources file.
Do you think anything is wrong with it?

```
deb http://[debian link]/debian bullseye main
deb http://deb[debian link]/debian bullseye-updates main
deb http://security[debian link] bullseye-security main
```

Here's the result of apt policy (a little trimmed because I can't post too many links):

````
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
     release v=22.04,o=LP-PPA-git-core,a=jammy,n=jammy,l=Git stable releases,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://security.[debian link] bullseye-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=11,o=Debian,a=stable-security,n=bullseye-security,l=Debian-Security,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.[debian link]
 500 http://deb.[debian link]/debian bullseye-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=11-updates,o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=bullseye-updates,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.[debian link]
 500 http://deb.[debian link]/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages
     release v=11.5,o=Debian,a=stable,n=bullseye,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.[debian link]
Pinned packages:```
````

Comment: from what I understand, my problem comes from git being linked to the ubuntu jammy thing, which indeed requires libc6 2.34

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system references the `git-core` Ubuntu PPA, which is where it’s trying to install `git` from. Ubuntu PPAs shouldn’t be used with Debian; in this particular case, you’re using a 22.04 PPA which relies on Ubuntu 22.04 packages, including a newer version of `libc6` than is available in Debian 11.

You can force the installation of `git` from Debian 11 with

```
sudo apt install -t bullseye git
```

but you should really remove the Ubuntu PPA.